# "Compressing" a linear function

Tags: linear-algebra, functions

I cannot for the life of me recall what the function I am thinking of is named.

For a linear function defined as $x_0 \mapsto x_1 ; y_0 \mapsto y_1$, what is the transform to achieve $x_0' \mapsto x_1' ; y_0 \mapsto y_1$?

Something like this:

[image: Graph]

Specifically in the graph above, I have a function $0 \mapsto 1; 0 \mapsto 1$, I want to transform it to $x_0' \mapsto x_1' ; 0 \mapsto 1$.

Comment: rescaling maybe? that's definitely a word people use, not sure if that's what you're after

Comment: @mm-aops That's not what I am thinking about. I remember doing something similar in computer graphics years ago, and this transform had a name.

Comment: In relation with CG, you may be thinking of histogram stretching, or just contrast enhancement. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_equation#Two-point_form

Comment: @YvesDaoust Thanks! Indeed, using two points form and clamping the input, I can do the calculation. Still trying to remember the name of the operation.  (Like "clamp" is a name of an "operation".)